# Fixed Size Caching Structure C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections, stack

Is there a built in LIFO collection that upon reaching a certain size, if another item is added it drops the item at the "bottom of the stack" (for want of a better way to describe it).

For instance, say I define the size to be 10 and I add some items so my "stack" looks something like this:

```
top
j
i
h
g
f
e
d
c
b
a
bottom
```

And then I push 'k' onto the top, 'a' would drop out of the bottom of the collection and be consigned to gc.

I'm sure I could implement similar functionality myself, but for the sake of not reinventing the wheel I'm wondering if any `.NET` or `C#` collection implements similar functionality?

Ideally I'd like for it to be a `generic` collection rather than just working with `object`s.

Comment: .NET doesn't have a fixed size queue implementation built-in but I'm fairly certain many others have provided their own implementations (so no need to start over)

Comment: Isn't the queue FIFO rather than LIFO?

Comment: Probaby meant [`Stack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx). Hth..

Comment: Well it holds for both queue or stack

Comment: You could use a fixed-size circular buffer as described in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/joaoportela/CircullarBuffer-CSharp). When the buffer is full, an item at the opposite end gets dropped.

Comment: If you want caching, the built in `MemoryCache` class is convenient and probably better than rolling your own stack.